# Ajax BeginForm send multiple requests even with single scripts references

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working on  .NET ASP.MVC application, in one of my views I implement `Ajax.BeginForm` to `_Layout.cshtml` I've added two scripts in that order:

- `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>`
- `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>`

The main bug is that when I use this form the post request is multiply, but only for second time. For example:I am adding  item to the database and showing the database elements list on the same site by partial view. When I first use this form item is added properly but for second time post request is multiplied and two same items appear. I've read about it and the reason is when you applied script reference twice that happens but I've only added my scripts reference once in `_Layout.cshtml` .

This is my view:

```
<div id="target">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "Home",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "target"

        }))

    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />           
    }

    @Html.Action("List")

</div>
```

This is my controller which returns partial view and var with List:

```
public ActionResult List()
    {
        ItemContext db = new ItemContext();
        var List = db.Items.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Items");

        return PartialView("List",List);
    }
```

And the controller responsible for adding new items into the db:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(Item Item)
        {
            ItemContext db = new ItemContext();
            db.Items.Add(Item);
            db.SaveChanges();


            return View("Index");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently returning the Index view from your `Add` action method which will render the index view with it's layout. The resulting html has a script tag which includes the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` js file. So injecting the result html of the index view to the current page's DOM will  load another copy of the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` js file to the page. This is the reason you are getting the "double post" behavior after your first form submit.

The solution is to return the partial view

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Item item)
{
    var db = new ItemContext();
    db.Items.Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();

    //Get the items again and pass tot he partial view to render the list
    var itemList = db.Items.ToList();
    return PartialView("List", itemList);
}
```

Now since you returning only the partial view for the  list of items, you need to update your main view so that your `UpdateTargetId` is a container div for the just the list, not the entire form.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "Home",
                            new AjaxOptions
                            {
                                HttpMethod = "POST",
                                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                UpdateTargetId = "target"

                            }))

{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
<div id="target">
    @Html.Action("List")
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it is working. For all the time I was thinking that I've got something wrong with this Ajax form.